# Are pictures legitimate as a proof in mathematics?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, alternative-proof, visualization, proof-without-words

While I'm studying Topology (teaching it myself with videos and books) I've seen some 'proofs' with pictorial approach and solution, I haven't seen it before. So is it legitimate?

Comment: The Professor who's using it frequently is Prof Dr Tadashi Tokieda

Comment: It is quite common, since one picture can save you weeks of  pointless calculations. You need to know what you're doing though, so it can be a bit difficult at the beginning. But at the end of the day this question is a bit similar to asking why we don't always write every proof in terms of the original axioms.

Comment: Personally, I think pictures serve as an introduction to some proofs. But although they might come in handy, I think that you should try and write it formally by hand.

Comment: If the necessary arguments are mentioned and the picture only visualizes the arguments, then, yes. Sometimes , a picture is already enough , as in the case of the Pythagorean theorem. But usually, a picture alone is not enough. In topology, I think there are statements that only need pictures, so I would say it depends on what you want to prove.

Comment: An example I can think of off the bat with usual introductory topology courses is set theoretic results, where pictures make more sense and save a lot of time.

Comment: In any case, a picture often helps to find the idea of the proof and often turns out to be very useful.

Comment: Well, for existence proofs, showing a picture of what is supposed to exist certainly should be valid proof. For example, if I want to prove that a graph with certain properties exists, drawing a graph with those properties should definitely be an existence proof.

Comment: In order to decide whether such a proof is valid, we'd have to see it.  The fact that it "uses pictures" isn't enough information to come to a conclusion. Perhaps you could narrow the discussion to a specific proof that you're thinking about.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That hits the nail on the head.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i know that it is always better to specify a question, but i simply want to know if in general a pictorial proof is valid and accepted, normaly im used to formal proofs containing logical implications...

Comment: @Maths The discussion above demonstrates that at least some proofs can be completely proven with a picture.  Does that satisfyingly answer your question?

Comment: i think it does. So in certain cases it can be used as proof-technique

Comment: Also, you might find the notion of a ["proof without words"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words) interesting

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "picture". Commutative diagrams? Yes, they qualify as proofs. Drawn pictures leaving out any algebraic or topological properties? Hardly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one? It's the simplest (and only) one I can think up just like that, that has to do with topology in that it is about continuity:

**Convex functions $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous**:

[image]

The interpretation being: The essential property of a convex function is that all line segments between points on the graph lie entirely above the graph. Assume you have a convex, discontinuous function, as shown - then there will be a line segment connecting two points on the graph, which passes under a portion of the graph.

***Edit:***

**Math** asks in the comments what it is exactly that this argument proves, so here's my attempt at clarifying:

There are two things to consider here, really:

*The concept of continuity*: is the rough graph really representative of what it means for a function to be continuous, or in this case discontinuous? The definition of continuity goes something like:

Given a function $f \colon A \rightarrow B$, with $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Pick a point $x \in A$; then $f$ is said to be continuous in $x$, if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \ \delta > 0 \colon |x - x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(x_0)|$ - the epsilon-delta argument feared and hated by young maths student everywhere. But what does it actually mean? What it says, really, is that no matter how small a 'box' you choose around $(x,f(x))$, you will always be able to find a bit of the function's graph near the point $(x,f(x))$. Dicontinuous at $x$, in contrast, means that you can find a value of $\epsilon$ where this is no longer the case - there will be a hole, where the graph jumps up or down, as illustrated in my rough drawing.

The other thing to keep in mind is the definition of *convexity*: A convex graph is one that always 'bends upward' - or in other words, any straight line between two points on the graph will always lie above the graph.

So, what did the argument above prove? Well, the drawing shows a 'convex' graph with a hole in it:

- I start by assuming that there is such a thing: a convex function that isn't continuous everywhere, and hopefully my considerations about what *discontinuous* means, have convinced you that this drawing is a valid representation of all such graphs.
- I then draw a line between two points on that graph, which as you can see is not entirely above the graph. I only need to find one such line to prove that this graph isn't convex, since the definition says that there mustn't be any lines that go below the graph.

This shows that a discontinuous function cannot be convex: it violates the definition. In other words, if a function is convex, then it can't be discontinuous - so it must be continuous.

This type of proof goes under the name *reductio ad absurdum*, and it is quite possibly one of the most annoying tools in logic: it so often leads to proofs where you know something is true, but you have no way of constructing a good example. Well, that's my opinion, any way.

Comment: just to clarify? What have you proven exactly ?

Comment: @Maths It's good that you ask - it is the mark of a good mathematician, that they keep asking until they feel convinced about every detail, however minute. I will add an edit to my answer with more details.

Comment: thanks, really appreciate your answer. It was really detailed, thank you for taking time. Furthermore, besides having seen a quick dive into convex function, it was a good illustrative example to my question.

Comment: no worries, it was a pleasure